# Jquery table td id

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which each `tr` is a record and each `td` is a column. When I use the `click` event and click on `tr`, I need both `tr` id and the 6th column `td` id.

Both `tr` and `td` id should be assigned to a variable.

How to do this with a jQuery selector?

Is this correct?

```
$(‘tr td).(‘click’, function (
{
});
```

Any help would be be appreciated. I tried this too:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(5)')
```

... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr id="row1">
        <td id="a1">A1</td>
        <td id="b1">B1</td>
        <td id="c1">C1</td>
        <td id="d1">D1</td>
        <td id="e1">E1</td>
        <td id="f1" class="sixth">F1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td id="a2">A2</td>
        <td id="b2">B2</td>
        <td id="c2">C2</td>
        <td id="d2">D2</td>
        <td id="e2">E2</td>
        <td id="f2" class="sixth">F2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
        <td id="a3">A3</td>
        <td id="b3">B3</td>
        <td id="c3">C3</td>
        <td id="d3">D3</td>
        <td id="e3">E3</td>
        <td id="f3"class="sixth">F3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('tr').click(function(){
        rowID = $(this)[0].id;
        celID = $(this).children('td:eq(5)')[0].id;
        alert('Row '+rowID+'\nCell '+celID);
    });

});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/npe7C/). (NOTE: The `class="sixth"` but was just for debugging and display purposes in jsFiddle.

**NOTE:** Revised solution after question was clarified by OP: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/npe7C/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('td:nth-child(6)').click(function(){
    alert( $(this)[0].id );
  });

}):
```

Comment: :If td is dynamic.say td id is some thing like this t_dyanlic values.

Comment: @user882583: So long as the value you want is held in the `id="x"` attribute, this code will get it. Look at the jsFiddle, perform some testing for yourself, and then, if problems persist, come back and ask again. Also, try and make your comments and questions as clear as possible - the less work we need to do to understand the problem, the more time we can commit to helping you solve it. Your comment here, for instance, does not make much sense - What is a "t_dyanlic value"?

Comment: :t_ is constant.Dyamic value will be varying,it comes from database.Here tr id will also be dyanmic some thing like this x_ constant then dynamic value;For eg:x_1 ,x_2.each row values changes.

Comment: @user882583: The code will do that. And 5 minutes of your time testing it in jsFiddle would have proven that. Please - test before you ask.

Comment: :How to remove x_ and get o/p as only o

Comment: @user882583: You select the "x_" bit and hit backspace and same thing with the "o/" ... My answers can only be as clear as your questions.

Comment: @user882583: A simple, and quick, bit of research into string replacements and regular expressions would show that `str.replace(/\D/g,'')` when `str` is a string variable will return only the numerals. So "abc123" becomes "123".
This is only a guess for what you were trying to do, as I can't be sure of what you are asking.

Comment: :If i click on 6 th td,i should get only that id.If i click on any other td,it should not give me a value.

Comment: @user882583: See revised answer. Next time, please, please, please take the time to make your question as clear as possible so you don't waste the time of people offering you answers.

Comment: :Pls,help me wit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994645/jquery-tagify-plug-in

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var cell = row.find('td:nth-child(6)');
```

Note that :nth-child() is 1-based, not 0-based, so use (6).

I'm posting on an iPad which doesn't lend itself to code-snippets, else I'd give you a more complete solution!

Comment: :See this http://jsfiddle.net/zXVbV/.When i click on first row,i need both tr and td id.td id will be dynamic.it should be done using click event.after getting into variable,i'ii be using if loop

Comment: Do you want the function to fire when you click anywhere on the row or only if you click the 6th column? If you want it anywhere, attach the function to $('tr') and use the above code to get the references.