# jquery tagify plug in

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery tagify for add tags on table cell,that is td.

Here is my work out http://jsfiddle.net/Pjcwf/32/

When you input a tag and press enter,it will change back to td with holding tags that was inputed but text box is moving front.

textbox should be removed after input tags.

in my local,i use dynamic id for td

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was the order in which the various elements of jsFiddle were coming together - the Script section is included in the HEAD section of the rendered page, so all the javascript libraries you were calling within the HTML section were not present before you tried to call them.

See the revision at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/Pjcwf/44/)